# How do i get from string buffer an u32 ? Rust

Tags: rust, buffer

How do I convert `[49]` buffer byte to number `1u32` without using `String?`

```rust
fn main() {
    // string "1"
    let buf: &[u8] =[49];
    // not working, expecting [0,0,0,1] to have good result.
    let num = u32::from_ne_bytes(buf.try_into().unwrap());

    println!("{}", num);
}
```

Result:

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: TryFromSliceError(())', src/main.rs:7:49
```

expected result `num: u32 = 1u32;`

Comment: are you trying to convert that string into u32?

Comment: is https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=92836f3f178158666680e56f137e8140 what you want ?

Comment: dont mind the string i have only buffer from the String. And i need to convert that buffer which is [49] to number 1u32. And i want that without using any string

Comment: Do you think "1" is stored as [0,0,0,1] in the buffer?

Comment: "1" is stored as [49] in the buffer

Comment: and [0,0,0,1] is stored number 1

Comment: Is your buffer only one-byte long? What would you do with a longer buffer?

Comment: I don't know what exactly you're trying to do, but what about `let buf: &[u8] = &[49]; let num:u32 = (buf[0] as char).to_digit(10).unwrap();`?

Comment: thats exactly what i wanted! Thanks

Comment: @prog-fh ASCII '1' is 49 (0x31). So their `&[49]` is really `b"1"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you only have one byte, you can convert it to char first, then convert it to a digit.

```
fn main() {
    let buf: &[u8] = &[49]; 
    let num = (buf[0] as char).to_digit(10).unwrap();
    println!("{}", num);
}
```

Output:
`1`

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understood, `from_ne_bytes` is not what you need.
You are trying to parse integer from string (even if it typed as slice of `u8`). You need to convert this slice into `&str` and then call `parse`:

```rust
let buf: &[u8] = &[49u8];

let s = std::str::from_utf8(buf).unwrap();

let num: u32 = s.parse().unwrap();
```